# Como usar o pipe na execução de programas python no terminal e para que serve?

Tags: python, terminal

exemplo :
python3 exemplo.py | exemplo2.py
Queria saber para que isso serve, percebi que de algum jeito eles se comunicam , mas não entendi a utilidade dessa propriedade.

Comment: Isso não é algo do Python, e sim do terminal. Basicamente, se vc tem `comando1 | comando2`, a saída do `comando1` se torna a entrada do `comando2`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9834086

Comment: Olha a nossa canônica sobre UNIX pipe no terminal aí. Pra mim é on-topic, ferramenta comum no contexto de programação. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O pipe, com o sinal `|` é na verdade uma funcionalidade do sistema operacional - disponibilizada pelo shell (no Linux e MacOS pode ser o bash, dentre outros, e no Windows até hoje é o "cmd").

O que ele faz na verdade é conectar um programa no outro através do "stdout"  - tudo o que o primeiro programa escreveria na tela é encaminhado para o segundo programa como se alguém tivesse digitado aquilo pelo teclado.

Então, programas simples, escritos das décadas de 70 e 80, foram criados de forma que se formou um eco-sistema muito grande de vários programinhas que podem ser interligados com pipe.

Os comandos de Unix find, grep, cat, echo, cut, tar, gzip além de linguagens de programação completas criadas centradas em ler e escrever em stdin e stdout como awk, tcl e perl - tiraram grande proveito disso, e até hoje é possível encontrar receitas com esses e outros comandos que fazem literalmente "mágica" :-)

Tanto o eco-sistema de aplicativos "reais" dos dias de hoje (2021), quanto as linguagens de programação mudaram - mesmo sistemas grandes no terminal dificilmente seguem a filosofia de serem "plugáveis diretamente" pelo pipe, (veja o exemplo do `git`) .  Claro, sempre tem alguma funcionalidade que vai ficar bem.

No caso do Python, num nível simples, sem configurar mais nada, tudo o que você fizer "print" num programa pode servir de entrada a um "input" em um segundo programa - então isso aqui funciona:

```py
# dados.py
print("João")
print("Brasileiro")
print("Campinas")
```

```py
# processa.py
nome = input()
nacionalidade = input()
cidade = input()

print(f"Recebi os dados de {nome}, {nacionalidade}, que mora em {cidade}")
```

E no meu termial, isso pode funcionar assim:

```bsh
gwidion@village ~/tmp62 $ python dados.py|python processa.py                                                                              
Recebi os dados de João, Brasileiro, que mora em Campinas
```

---

Essa comunicação pode ir bem além desses dados simples - assim como o stdout do programa1 está conectado ao programa2, por dentor do Python é possível conectar de volta, a saída do programa2 a uma entrada independente para o programa1 - o módulo  `subprocess` do Python permite todo esse controle, e você pode criar programas especificamente para conversarem entre si.

Comment: Obrigado ! Mas isso não seria equivalente a digitar no terminal : py processa.py < dados.py   ?

Comment: então - nesse exemplo sim - mas o "dados.py" poderia pegar esses dados de qualquer lugar-  de um banco de dados, de um arquivo texto, de uma requisição web - -assim como o "processa.py' poderia fazer quauqer coisa com eles: zipar, gravar num banco de dados, etc.. .
E ter 3 campos fixos e distintos também não ajuda - é um exmeplo ruin - é mais usado para dados homogêneos: o segundo programa trata todo um texto que é saída do programa 1, etc...